# Org DEADLINE empty for repeated task

Tags: org-mode

Consider the following in an .org file:

```
* Meetings
** TODO Meeting Thing                      :meeting:
   DEADLINE: <2016-04-15 Fri 11:00 +1w -5d>
   :PROPERTIES:
   :LOGGING: nil
   :END:
```

I typically use `C-c C-t` a few times to mark such entries to `DONE`, after which Org will reschedule.

However, in this case, Org is rescheduling the entry with an empty date, as follows:

```
DEADLINE:
```

Emacs (snapshot) version is 25.1.50.2. Org version is 8.3.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A discussion [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/106344) indicates that this is related to a change/bug in a Emacs commit c23c965bb9d0. Updating Org (as discussed in the thread) solved this.